# Conditioning after sick leave

Tags: exercise, kung-fu, strength, kickboxing

What type of conditioning should I perform after being out sick for 2 weeks? I'm taking a Muay Thai test in one week and going back to classes for Jeet Kun Do and Wing Chun in  a few days. I usually Strength and condition 2 days a week  and take classes 3 days with one day rest and stretch and Sunday one on one technique drills and cardio.

Comment: ? is this a martial arts question? or is this a fitness question?

Answer (score 2):

We got this [exact question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/9647/1771) over at fitness.SE. Essentially you just get back into it a little slower, with a little less intensity (less weight on the bar, running shorter distances, sprinting a little slower). Not much special to it, except crossing your Ts and dotting your Is. Make sure the sickness is really gone and start training carefully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should watch out not to get sick again. For me use your 50% of your strenght when going back to train. Your have drained a lot of strength during recovery. Keep a medium pace for your training for a week or two and then gradually increase your training pace.